# SwifUI focused keyboard intercepting UINavigation bar actions?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

My code looks like this: I have SwiftUI view embed in UIHostingController embed in UINavigationController:

```
 func smsValidationView() -> UIViewController {
    let view = STAccounts.SMSValidationView(store: self.store.scope(
        state: { SMSValidationViewReducer.State(
            authentication: $0.authentication,
            numberOfDigits: $0.numberOfDigits,
            lastClickedIndex: $0.lastClickedIndex,
            verificationId: $0.verificationId,
            formattedOTP: $0.formattedOTP,
            validPhoneNumber: $0.validPhoneNumber,
            isFocused: $0.isFocused,
            SMSValidationCountdownStartTime: $0.SMSValidationCountdownStartTime,
            allowResend: $0.allowResendOTP,
            isVerificationSuccessful: $0.isMFAVerificationSuccessful,
            isMFALoginFlow: $0.isMFALoginFlow,
            backgroudStyle: $0.authBackgroundStyle,
            resolverContainer: $0.resolverContainer,
            isMFALoading: $0.isMFALoading
        )},
        action: { .accountsView(.smsValidationView($0)) })
    )
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    return createMFALoginNavigationViewController(with: controller)
    return controller
}
  func createMFALoginNavigationViewController<V: View>(with hostingController: UIHostingController<V>) -> UINavigationController {
    let backImage = ConsumerUI.Asset.Icons.chevronLeft.image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: hostingController)
    navigationController.navigationBar.configureConsumerDefaultStyle()
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    navigationController.presentationController?.delegate = self
    hostingController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImage, style: .plain, closure: { [weak hostingController] _ in
        hostingController?.dismiss(animated: ConsumerUIModule.areAnimationsEnabled)
    })
    return navigationController
}
```

This is the SwiftUI View itself:

```
public struct SMSValidationView: View {

enum MFAFlow {
    case login
    case registration
}

@State private var isKeyboardShown: Bool = false

public var store: StoreOf<SMSValidationViewReducer>
@ObservedObject private var viewStore: ViewStoreOf<SMSValidationViewReducer>

private var verifyButtonDisabled: Bool {
    !viewStore.formattedOTP.isNumber
}

public init(store: StoreOf<SMSValidationViewReducer>) {
    self.store = store
    self.viewStore = ViewStore(store)
}

public var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 35.0) {
                Text("A code has been sent via SMS to the phone\nnumber provided. Please enter the code below\nto verify your identity.")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .appFont(weight: .regular, size: 14.0)
                otpView
                    .frame(height: 80)
                resendSMSView
                    .zIndex(2)
            }
            .padding()
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)
        }
        Spacer()
        if !isKeyboardShown {
            MFAProcceedButtonView(
                text: "VERIFY CODE",
                isDisabled: verifyButtonDisabled,
                isOpaque: viewStore.isMFALoginFlow,
                isLoading: Binding(get: { viewStore.isMFALoading }, set: { _ in })
            ) {
                if viewStore.isMFALoginFlow {
                    viewStore.send(.login2FA)
                } else {
                    viewStore.send(.register2FA)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onReceive(keyboardPublisher) { value in
        isKeyboardShown = value
    }
    .onAppear {
        viewStore.send(.onAppear)
    }
    .onDisappear {
        viewStore.send(.onDisappear)
    }
    .navigationTitle("2-Step Verification")
    .background(currrentBackgroundView)
}
```

The issue is that when the keyboard is focused, the navigation back button doesn't receive events. but as soon as I dismiss the keyboard it starts working again. I didn't manage to find any info about this issue. Did anyone have a similar case and is there any workaround?